# $\operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]_{(x)}$ are both one point

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm working through professor Vakil's book on algebraic geometry, which I recommend (it can be found at https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf). I'd like to check my answers to Exercises 3.2.A(a) and 3.2.A(b).

**3.2.A(a)** Describe $\operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$.

*Answer:* since the prime ideals of the quotient ring $R/\mathfrak{a}$ are uniquely determined by the prime ideals of $R$ that contain $\mathfrak{a}$, a prime ideal of $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ is given by some $\mathfrak{b} \in \operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]$ such that $\mathfrak{b} \supset (\epsilon^2)$. However, since $\mathfrak{b}$ is prime, $\epsilon \in \mathfrak{b}$. Therefore, $\mathfrak{b} \supset (\epsilon)$, and as a consequence, $\operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}k = \{pt\}$.

**3.2.A(b)** Describe $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]_{(x)}$.

*Answer:* Using corollary 11.20(2) of https://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/13Ed.pdf, the prime ideals of $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]_{(x)}$ are uniquely determined by the prime ideals of $k[x]$ contained in $(x)$. Assume $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ is such that $(0) \subsetneq \mathfrak{p} \subsetneq (x)$. Since $k[x]$ is a PID, $\mathfrak{p} = (xa)$ for some $a \in k[x]$. However, since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime and $x \notin \mathfrak{p}$, $a \in \mathfrak{p}$. Then $xa\mid a$ so $x$ is a unit, contradiction. We conclude $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]_{(x)} \simeq \{(x)\}$.

I will appreciate any comments! :)

Comment: The zero ideal is still prime in one of the two...

Comment: Also note that since $k$ is a field, $k[x]$ is a PID, and hence every nonzero prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: $k[x]_{(x)}$ is the localization at a principal maximal ideal so it is a DVR

Comment: In case 1: $\operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}k = \{(0)\}$. In case 2:
Since $k[x]$ is a domain, $k[x]_{(x)}$ is also a domain. Hence, $\{0\}\in Spec(k[x]_{(x)})$. Now since $dim(k)=0$, we have $dim(k[x])=1$ and since $k[x]_{(x)}$ is local we have, $Spec(k[x]_{(x)})=\{\{0\}, xk[x]_{(x)}\}$.

Comment: The isomorphisms you wrote down are not isomorphisms of schemes. This is very important!

Comment: Thank you very much @AymanHourieh I think this insight is very helpful since k[x]_(x) is a local ring.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur this is important to keep in mind, two points is not exactly one point :)

Comment: thank you @reuns however I'm not familiar with DVRs

Comment: thank you @Es.Ro these are full solid answers to the exercises :)

Comment: thank you @SamirCanning indeed by these \simeq I meant bijections of sets, not yet serious business!